# Writing query results to CSV causes "_csv.Error: sequence expected"

Tags: python, csv, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to write the results of a query to a CSV file.  I tried the solution from this other SO question: [dump csv from sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952366/dump-csv-from-sqlalchemy), but got `_csv.Error: sequence expected`.  Why am I getting this error?  How do I correctly write my query results to CSV?

```
fh = open('data.csv', 'wb')
outcsv = csv.writer(fh)
result = Grant.query.filter(Grant.pi_name==(piname)).all()
for res in result:
    outcsv.writerows(res)
fh.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you tried `outcsv.writerows` expects a collection of tuples to write.  The query you wrote queries a *model*, which returns instances of that model.  Additionally, you're passing each row individually to `writerows`, but as the plural in the name suggests you should pass *all* the rows.  Query the model's *table* instead, and pass the result to `writerows` directly.

```
entries = db.session.query(Grant.__table__).filter(Grant.pi_name == pi_name)

with open('entries.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(entries)
```