# Steps to Extract data from mysqldb to csv using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I'm a python beginner, I want to know the steps and how to write the code to extract data from mysql DB to  a csv file.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm afraid though your questions is way too broad. This community is to help you out with a specific code problem. So we would need to see what you've tried so far to solve your problem. Please have a look at the help section https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

**Example MySQL Database:**

[image]

**Solution:**

You can use sqlalchemy with pandas to import the data into a pandas DataFrame from a mysql database.

*Note: You may need to install PyMySql if sqlalchemy.read_sql() won't work.*

A pandas DataFrame has method to_csv() which can be used to export the DataFrame into a CSV file.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from pandas import read_sql

# MySQL database connection
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://%s:%s@localhost:3306/%s"
                       %('username','password','dbname'),echo=False)
source_connection = engine.connect()

# Read the data from the database connection into a pandas DataFrame
df = read_sql('SELECT * FROM test', con=source_connection)

df.to_csv('/users/testuser/myfile.csv')
```

**This creates a csv file:**

[image]

*Note: DataFrame.to_csv() has several options for formatting the data being exported. See documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html*

**ALTERNATIVE ANSWER**

[dump csv from sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952366/dump-csv-from-sqlalchemy)